# How to pass environment variable of hudson as a parameter for svn build

Tags: svn, build, branch, hudson

My requirement is I need the scope of Hudson's environment variable in the subproject's build parameter for svn url.

I want to set SVN Branch name as an environment variable of Hudson, as I want it to be used by all my projects configured there.

If I access my environment variable [BUILD_BRANCH] as

http://svn/repos/project/subproj/branches/${BUILD_BRANCH}

the url is not getting replaced with the value.

But in the same case if I have BUILD_BRANCH as String Parameter for Parameterised Build in each subproj the url is replaced with value. But I cannot not change the branch value [build parameter value] each time in all the projects. Also the downstream projects were not able to access the build parameters [String] of the calling projects.

Comment: As a courtesy, we usually give feedback if the answer solves your problem and also mark the best answer (the one that describes the needed solution best or that lead you down the right path to solve the problem). If you do this, people are more inclined to help you in the future.

Comment: yes, i have tried that and it works as follows:define parmater after clicking on "this build is parameterized" and set variable BUID_BRANCH=Branch1,2  and  svn url =
http://svn/repos/project/subproj/branches/$BUID_BRANCH. Though the SVN URL will show as failed while setting it but the variable value BUID_BRANCH will be picked up on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

There is a checkbox called: "This build is Parameterized" in the build's configuration.

If you enable that, you will be able to create parameters to this specific build.

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify your problem. You have defined an environment variable, BUILD_BRANCH and want to be able to reference it from within a parameter for your build. Is that right?

If that's the case, then I have solved your problem!

When parameters are evaluated (and any variables referenced within them are expanded), you don't have access to environment variables, so the value of the parameter ends up being the literal string '${BUILD_BRANCH}', rather than being expanded to the environment definition of $BUILD_BRANCH.

Then when you reference the parameter from shell script, the value of the parameter is surrounded in single quotes, preventing the extra layer of indirection from being resolved, so you get the name of your environment variable, rather than its value.

The solution is to add eval to the start of each line of shell script where you reference the parameter, which *will* resolve the extra layer, and the variable will work.

One last thing- you don't have to do this if you are referencing a previous parameter. So if Param1 is foo, and Param2 is ${foo} bar, this will work, because the parameters are evaluated in order. If the parameter values were switched, however, you would need to use eval.

Comment: This doesn't work because it needs to be in the repository URL field which is not a script.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no current way to use a environmental variable to adjust the subversion repository location.  What I decided to do is to edit the `config.xml` files outside with a script.

This may not work for you if the value of that variable is changing programmatically, but for us, I wanted to be able to migrate our jobs between branches and trunk which is done every sprint and is a manual process.

Some sort of script like the following works for us:

```
FROM_SVN_PATH="svnserver.com/trunk"
TO_SVN_PATH="svnserver.com/branches/1.1"
cd jobs
for f in */config.xml
do
    sed -e "s,$FROM_SVN_PATH,$TO_SVN_PATH," < "$f" > "$f.t"
    mv "$f" "$f.ORG"
    mv "$f.t" "$f"
done
```

If you are using Jenkins, you can then go to "Manage Jenkins" and select "Reload Configuration from Disk".

Answer (score -1):

set BUILD_BRANCH in ManageHudson->Configure System->Global properties->Environment Variables

Comment: My Hudson can access the environment variables, but only the ones that are defined globally. Any change to the environment variables usually require a reboot of the whole system (os reboot) since my Hudson runs as a service.

Comment: I have already provided BUILD_BRANCH in Env Variables under Global properties but it doesnt work. Thatsy I raised this question.